# Breakout game in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here's the code for a Breakout style game I made in Python. I was hoping to see if someone can give me some advice on improving anything.

I have a bug with the collision between the ball and the top bricks/blocks, and I'm still working on that. Since it doesn't follow "code review" I have removed what I said earlier and want to focus on the code in general and not fixing bugs.

The following is from several different files. I wasn't sure if there was a better way of formatting it here.

```
import time
from turtle import Screen
from paddle import Paddle
from ball import Ball
from brick import Brick
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
import random

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Breakout Remake")
screen.tracer(0)

paddle = Paddle((0, -275))
ball = Ball((random.randint(-300, 300), 0))
scoreboard = Scoreboard()

brick_list = []
x, y  = 350, 285
for i in range(0, 4):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        brick_list.append(Brick((x, y)))
        x -= 85
    x = 350
    y -= 25

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(paddle.go_left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(paddle.go_right, "Right")

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(ball.move_speed)
    screen.update()
    ball.move()

    # Detect collision with side wall
    if ball.xcor() > 370 or ball.xcor() < -360:
        ball.bounce_side()

    # Detect collision against top
    if ball.ycor() > 280:
        ball.bounce_top()

    # Detect collision with paddle
    if ball.distance(paddle) < 50 and ball.ycor() <= -260:
        ball.bounce_paddle()

    # Detect paddle miss
    if ball.ycor() < -300:
        scoreboard.display()
        game_is_on = False

    # Detect brick hit
    for brick in brick_list:
        if ball.distance(brick) < 25:
            print(ball.position())
            ball.bounce_brick()
            brick.hideturtle()
            brick_list.remove(brick)
            scoreboard.score += 1

screen.exitonclick()    


from turtle import Turtle
import random
class Ball(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("circle")
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)
        self.x_move = -10 * random.choice([-1, 1])
        self.y_move = -10
        self.move_speed = 0.1
        self.speed = 6

    def move(self):
        new_x = self.xcor() + self.x_move
        new_y = self.ycor() + self.y_move
        self.goto(new_x, new_y)

    def bounce_side(self):
        self.x_move *= -1

    def bounce_top(self):
        self.y_move = -abs(self.y_move)

    def bounce_brick(self):
        self.y_move *= -1
        self.x_move *= 1.05
        self.y_move *= 1.05

    def bounce_paddle(self):
        self.y_move = abs(self.y_move)

    # for later use if game restart is implemented
    # def reset_position(self):
    #     self.goto((random.randint(-300, 300), 0))
    #     self.x_move = -10 * random.choice([-1, 1])

from turtle import Turtle
class Scoreboard(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        with open("data.txt", mode="r") as file:
            self.high_score = int(file.read())
        self.penup()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.color("white")
        self.goto(-200, 0)
    
    def display(self):
        self.write(f"Game Over\nScore: {self.score} | High Score: {self.high_score}", font=("Calibri", 40, "bold"))

from turtle import Turtle
class Brick(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=4)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)

from turtle import Turtle
class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position):
        #inherit superclass (Turtle)
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=6)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)

    def go_left(self):
        if self.xcor() >= -320:
            new_x = self.xcor() - 40
            self.goto(new_x, self.ycor())

    def go_right(self):
        if self.xcor() <= 320:
            new_x = self.xcor() + 40
            self.goto(new_x, self.ycor())
```

Comment: General review of your code is on topic but fixing your collision bug is not

Comment: Okay, sorry. I will remove the collision bug part. I still would like to know about any improvements to be made other than that as the program still works even with the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This nested loop:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    for i in range(0, 9):
```

really shouldn't use the same iteration variable name for both levels - unless, of course, it's `_` indicating that they're both unused (which they are). However, this disguises what you're *actually* iterating over, which is `x` and `y`. So it should look something like

```
for y in range(285, 185, -25):
    for x in range(350, -415, -85):
```

From your `screen = Screen()` through your `exitonclick()`, all of that code should be moved into a `main()` function. Luckily this is quite easy as your classes hold no references to those variables.

Add type hints such as

```
def __init__(self, position: tuple[int, int]) -> None:
```

Rather than `-10 * random.choice([-1, 1])` why not just write

```
random.choice((-10, 10))
```

`data.txt` is not a good name for that file; consider instead `high_score.txt`. Don't open it in `r` - it will always fail the first time around; instead create it if it doesn't exist:

```
    with open("high_score.txt", 'a+') as file:
        score_str = file.read()
    if score_str == '':
        self.high_score = 0
    else:
        self.high_score = int(score_str)
```

And yes, your collision code needs some love. It's not enough to just `xcor()` on your object to get its centre; you need to calculate the *edge* of your objects and do the math to see whether they collide.